# React Meteor components not updating

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I'm using React with Meteor and am having trouble keeping my data updated. Here is my `getMeteorData()` code in a `Conversation` component

```
getMeteorData() {
    var vertices_handle = Meteor.subscribe('VertexIDs', this.props.conversation_id);
    return {
        vertices: Vertices.find({conversation: this.props.conversation_id}).fetch(),
        ready: vertices_handle.ready()
    };
}
```

The subscription only returns the IDs of the posts (vertices) and I use this data to render more components:

```
renderPostList() {
    return this.data.vertices.map((post) => {
        return <PostThread
                key = {post._id}
                root_id = {post._id}
                conversation_id = {this.props.conversation_id} />;
    });
}
```

Within the `PostThread` component I subscribe to each post individually by its ID to get the rest of the data as needed. However, when I remove something from the Vertices collection, the `Conversation` component doesn't seem to be updating. I can see in MeteorToys that the Vertices collection on the client has removed a post, but this change ***sometimes*** isn't reflected in the UI. Sometimes when a post is removed the UI updates correctly but other times it doesn't and I have not been able to find a pattern to this.

Comment: I have tried fixing this in many different ways but have been unsuccessful. My current workaround is to check within the `PostThread` component if the current post's ID is contained in the subscription data and if not the render function just returns false.